# Webservice works through curl command line but not PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I'm trying to translate a curl command I was given into a command I can run through PHP.

The command is:

```
curl -F customerid=902 -F username=API1 -F password=somepassword -F reportname=1002 http://somerandomurl.com/api/v1/getreportcsv
```

When I try to run this through PHP (and eventually through C#) however, the web service returns an error. Any idea what could be wrong with my code that is making it error? I think the web service must be very specific about the headers/request:

```
$url = "http://somerandomurl.com/api/v1/getreportcsv";
$fields = [
  "customerid" => "902",
  "username"   => "API1",
  "password"   => "somepassword",
  "reportname" => "1002"
];

$fields_string = "";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
```

Wireshark shows the following differences:

The below is the one that works:

```
POST /somefolder/api/v1/getreportcsv HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 65
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

customerid=902&username=API1&password=somepassword&reportname=1002&HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 6
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 22:51:23 GMT

ERROR
```

Whereas this one works:

```
POST /someurl/api/v1/getreportcsv HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
Host: somehost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 459
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------4b0d14cc31a40c5b

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

--------------------------4b0d14cc31a40c5b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customerid"

902
--------------------------4b0d14cc31a40c5b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

API1
--------------------------4b0d14cc31a40c5b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

somepassword
--------------------------4b0d14cc31a40c5b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reportname"

1002
--------------------------4b0d14cc31a40c5b--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 23:13:57 GMT

2000
...snip... the results of the api
```

Obviously they are very different requests, however I wouldn't expect something to be so specific?

Comment: What is the error being returned?

Comment: Also, you should look into using `http_build_query()` instead of your looping/trimming. Might be more efficient since it's a native function.

Comment: Simply says "ERROR", however it is irrelevant as this was coded by the other end. They request is obviously different using my code above to what it would be if it was run through the command they gave us

Comment: What is the error? Also, you can use `http_build_query($fields)` to build your $fields_string instead foreach&rtrim, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Yeah that is not the greatest of error reporting from that end! Have you tried going to that formed link in your browser to see if it will return anything?

Comment: Yeah...same thing! I've added the requests/responses from Wireshark from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems very specific to the service in question.

However, the problem might be with headers. According to [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F):

> -F [...] causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type
>   `multipart/form-data` according to RFC 2388

However, according to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CURLOPT_POST` option will send data using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

According to the same manual, if value of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to `multipart/form-data`. You may also try to set the content type explicitly as a header.

Try setting the following cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));
```

If that does not work, it might help analysing all the headers send by the command line curl using the `-v` parameter and try to set them. Also might be good idea to set content length header explicitly.

Comment: You legend.. that worked! Now just to transfer this into `HttpClient` in C#

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :) I'm afraid I can't help much with C# tho.. good luck!